# Why don't I get all my properties when I use the & operator in TS?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface like this:

```
export interface ISizeAndColor {
  color: string;
  size: string;
  amount: string;
}
```

I want to add another object to it, the `product_id`. So when I make this:

```
selectedOptions: ISizeAndColor & { product_id: string; }[]
```

then I only have access to my `product_id` not the other properties. (When I map it, it is an array.) What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you intending the intersection to be on the things _inside_ the array?

Comment: Yes. Did you mean `(ISizeAndColor & { product_id: string; })[]`?

Comment: thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brackets `[]` have a higher operator priority than the union operator `&`. Therefore if you want to have an array of your union type you'll have to put it in braces:

```js
selectedOptions: (ISizeAndColor & { product_id: string; })[];
```

Comment: thank you very much